# Походження слова "бурса"?

Tags: етимологія

Нещодавно я почув про походження слова "бурса", де точно йшлося, що воно потрапило до нашої мови із німецької. Однак, я захотів перевірити почуту інформацію і одразу ж на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0) побачив:

**Бу́рса** (лат. bursa — мішок)

Та виникло питання: "Що спільного у бурси із мішками?".
Заглянувши до [ЕСУМУ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf) (ст.304) побачив, що воно потрапило до нашої мови із польської, куди потрапило із латинської, де мало значення: "шкіра, шкіряний гаманець, товариство".

Цікаво дізнатися як саме першопочаткове значення слова "bursa"? І якщо воно означає "мішок", то чому саме це слово було вибране для назви духовних училищ та гуртожитків при братських школах? Чи можлвио інформація на Вікіпедії невірна?

Comment: Чув таку версію що це від назви турецького міста Бурса, яка свого часу (1326—1365) навіть була столицею Османьскої імперії.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не можу доказно пояснити «чому слово вибране для», *мішок* може означати:

- *Збірність*.
- А також *плату*, шчо імовірніше, оскільки значна частина слів витекли сюди.

Деякі [џерела](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/bursa#bursa_(j%C4%99zyk_polski)) пишуть, шчо польська взяла не одразу від латиньської, а з німецького [*Börse*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/B%C3%B6rse#German), котре наразі, навіть украӥнсьскою, прижило ся як [*біржа*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0). Раніше, як і польською в [15 сторічї](http://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=46083&id_znaczenia=5207742), значило гаманця. Такого подібного переходу з *гаманець* в штибу *гуртожитка* помітно лиш в польськіј, инші мови переважно цӧго прямо взяли. Дешчо подібниј перехід, по-моєму, був з словом [*пансіон*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD) він *pensio*.

Шчодо першослова і значіня, то [тут простіше](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bursa#Latin).

Латинь — *шкура*, себто *шкіра тварини*, пряме запозиченє з елаѕької [*βύρσα*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CF%8D%CF%81%CF%83%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek).